# NOT IN with subquery not returning correct results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running this query in PostgreSQL to find out which states are in `customer` table but missing in `_customer` table. I know in this case that Kuala Lumpur is missing (technically not a state, I know). But the query is returning nothing.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ("Billing Address State")
FROM customer
WHERE "Billing Address State" NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT("Billing Address State")
    FROM _customer
);
```

Other queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ("Billing Address State")
FROM customer

NT
South Australia
Kuala Lumpur
Hertfordshire
NSW
Bangkok
West Java
Queensland
New South Wales
Western Australia
Stockholm
Victoria
WA
QLD
Gauteng
Australian Capital Territory
SA
Other
TAS
Northern Territory
VIC
Rhondda Cynon Taf
Tasmania
ACT
Îles du Vent
North Lanarkshire
Norfolk
Dublin
```

And

```
SELECT DISTINCT("Billing Address State")
FROM _customer;

NT
South Australia
Hertfordshire
NSW
Bangkok
West Java
Queensland
New South Wales
Western Australia
Stockholm
Victoria
ACT
Îles du Vent
WA
North Lanarkshire
Norfolk
Dublin
QLD
Gauteng
Australian Capital Territory
SA
Other
TAS
Northern Territory
VIC
Rhondda Cynon Taf
Tasmania
```

Complement of the original query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ("Billing Address State")
FROM customer
WHERE "Billing Address State" IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT("Billing Address State")
    FROM _customer
);
```

returns everything except Kuala Lumpur. In other words, Kuala Lumpur is in `_customer` and it's not there, both at the same time.

Comment: Can "Billing Address State" be null in _customer? That would explain it, because when at least one element is null, `NOT IN` returns nothing.

Comment: Yes! That was the problem

Comment: Don't use `DISTINCT` with `IN` or `NOT IN` by the way. You are supposed to tell the DBMS what data you are interested in (customers not in the other table here), not how to achieve that. Leave that to the DBMS; it will decide whether to perform a `DISTINCT` operation or not to optimally run this.

Comment: I've posted the solution as an answer, so future readers with the same problem find the solution easily.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function on a column, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. Remove the parentheses t omake things clearer, i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT "Billing Address State" FROM ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When at least one element in `NOT IN` is null, the query returns nothing. The argumentation is somewhat that the DBMS cannot guarantee that a value is not in the list when one of the values in the list is a value unknown to the DBMS :-)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ("Billing Address State")
FROM customer
WHERE "Billing Address State" NOT IN (
    SELECT "Billing Address State"
    FROM _customer
    WHERE "Billing Address State" IS NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 3):

`NOT IN` becomes tricky when the sub-query returns null-values, as @Thorsten Kettner already has explained. I always recommend a switch to the "null-safe" `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "Billing Address State"
FROM customer c1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM _customer c2
    WHERE c2."Billing Address State" = c1."Billing Address State");
```

Or, in this case you can simply use `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT "Billing Address State"
FROM customer
EXCEPT
SELECT "Billing Address State"
FROM _customer
```

Comment: Wouldn't `EXISTS` be much slower?

Comment: @Farshid, slower than what? I don't know Postgresql well enough to answer that question. Try and see!

Answer (score 0):

you can also go with left join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "Billing Address State"
FROM customer c1
LEFT JOIN _customer c2 ON c2."Billing Address State" = c1."Billing Address State"
WHERE c2.<whatever> IS NULL;
```

Comment: Note that `c2.<whatever>` should be a non-nullable column.